# Почему не работает вставка элементов в DOM на IPhone?

Tags: ajax, ios, iphone, safari

Имеется функция JS, которая корректно работает на всех устройствах, кроме тех что на IOS. Особую проблему создают мобильные устройства типа **IPhone**. В проекте есть ряд похожих функций, но все они умирают на стадии встраивания нового контента в DOM (на IOS). Запрос на сервер и ответ - это работает верно. **Данные передаются и их даже можно вывести алертом, но как только дело доходит до .html() всё падает.** У самого нет никаких устройств на IOS, поэтому конкретнее описать ситуацию нет возможности.

**Подскажите, что тут не так? В какую сторону двигаться?**

```
function loadbag(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "functions/loadbag.php",
    dataType: "html", //json
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        data = JSON.parse(data); 
        if($(window).width() > 770){
            $("#bag-point").html(' ' + data["main"]);
        } else if(data["alt"] != null){
            $("#bag-point").html(' ' + data["alt"]);
        }  else if(data["alt"] == null){
            $("#bag-point").empty();
        }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: `dataType: "html", //json` и `JSON.parse(data);` ?

Comment: @Igor, да, я знаю про этот недочет, спасибо, однако моя проблема не связана с этим. Проверял и с типом json, никаких изменений: всё работает, но только не на IOS

Comment: что значит _всё падает_?

Comment: @Grundy, код обрывается на моменте вставки (.html()). Данные передаются верно и их получается вывести в консоль или через алерт, но встроить в DOM нет. Это то, что я понял из объяснений владельца IPhone)

Comment: В приведенном коде нет каких-то специфичных особенностей, которые могли бы как-то влиять на работу в ios. Без конкретики что именно происходит: ошибка, ничего, что-то странное можно только гадать, почему на ios поведение отличается. Это может быть из-за значения в `data`, а может в совсем другом коде или даже css

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо. Буду пробовать что-то сделать иначе.

Comment: @ValentinMihai, здесь скорее нужна отладка. потому что иначе можно долго мыкаться.